# Why was Roberto "Bob" Orci fired from "Star Trek Beyond"?

Tags: production, star-trek, star-trek-beyond

Roberto Bob Orci is an execute producer and writer, whom previously co-wrote with Alexander Kurtzman for their K/O Paper Products Production Company and often collaborated with JJ Abrams/Bad Robot Productions.

In May of 2014 he was hired to co-write and make his directorial debut on [*Star Trek Beyond*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Beyond), but by December of the same year, he was pushed back to producer, which finally resulted with Simon Pegg rewriting the script and Justin Lin replacing him as director. He was fired!

At the time, there were no reasons given as to the dismissal, but the following [article](https://movieweb.com/star-trek-3-story-director-roberto-orci-fired/) claims it had to do with the script:

> Yesterday, it was widely reported
>   that Paramount had removed Roberto Orci as director on their upcoming
>   sequel Star Trek 3. Though, he will be staying on as a producer. At
>   the time, no reason was given for his dismissal. Today, Badass Digest
>   claim the axe came down because of the script, which is also being
>   dumped.
>
> New writers J.D. Payne and Patrick McKay co-wrote the screenplay for
>   Star Trek 3 alongside Roberto Orci, which the former director claimed
>   was completed back in August. In October, stars Karl Urban and John
>   Cho both praised the story, claiming it would 'blow fans away'.
>   Apparently the studio thought otherwise, as this latest report states
>   that the screenplay was one of the problem factors, and resulted in
>   Roberto Orci being removed from the director's chair.

But beyond this firing, Alexander Kurtzman had shifted heavier towards his Secret Hideout Production Company with partner Heather Kadin, while Roberto Orci has not since been seen anywhere working on anything NEW.

So my question is, **why was Roberto Orci fired and/or would a bad script, which wasn't his alone, really earn him such a reputation that he wouldn't get work in the industry again?** Or is there another reason?

Comment: If the studio don't like the script and the director isn't willing to do what the studio wants...of course they can fire him. As for not working...says who? Plus he'd never directed before so this would leave a bad taste in a number of mouths.

Comment: Ok, I was asking if it was enough to cause this not that it isn't possible, but he wasn't the only one working the script and no where did I read specifically that he wouldn't cooperate (if there is evidence to support it, great!). He hasn't worked on a single NEW project post K/O Paper Products (IMDb + plus I follow his career). He still is the EP of Hawaii Five-0, which he co-produced when he was still with Kurtzman, but everything else is canceled and not "new"

Comment: I'm just asking for some evidence, even if it's by comparison.

Comment: The reason both the studio and Orci gave was creative differences (presumably over the script).....neither is likely to deviate from that comment. Other involved people (Pegg) stated that the script was not what the studio wanted so I'm not sure what you are is really after. As for work...IMDB differs that he is in pre-production of *Locke & Key* as well as continuing with H50...I wouldn't call that "not working in the industry". Granted he hasn't directed but this would have been a first and, as I said, he didn't have the best experience.

Comment: That is an old entry for Locke & Key that he and Kurtzman were attached to, but FOX passed on it. It now is with Carlton Cuse/Scott Dirreckson originally for Hulu, but they also passed, but Netflix is close to a series order with those two still attached!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locke_%26_Key

Comment: Again Hawaii Five-0 is not new/existed before 2014 and it is unclear if his role was diminished since this firing, and since Kurtzman is also an co-executive producers, IMO it seems like it goes beyond this, because Kurtzman also doesn't want to work with him anymore and that's why I wondered if there are "other" factors contributing to this backlash.

Comment: If there is no other explanation and/or that this kind of backlash is normal over a script, then that's fine. But I'm only asking to confirm or see if there is some other reason.

Comment: Collin Trevorrow was fired from star wars, but he still has two new projects: Jurassic World 3 & Intelligent life.